# How does "while" statement in JavaScript evaluate decremented variable?

Tags: javascript, while-loop, evaluation, decrement

I got a simple script that works fine:

```js
var PHONE_PRICE = 20.5,
    ACCESSORIES_PRICE = 12.2,
    TAX_RATE = 0.098,
    THRESHOLD = 30,
    MIN_PURCHASE = taxed(PHONE_PRICE, TAX_RATE);

var balance = prompt("your balance"), phoneQt = 0, accessoriesQT = 0;

function taxed(purchase, tax) {
    return purchase * (1 + tax);
}

/*
 * If the amount of total purchase exceed the balance, 
 * the buying stops.
*/

// MIN_PURCHASE prevent the buying to reduce your balance to negative value, as in -$20
while (true) {
    if (balance < MIN_PURCHASE) {
        break;
    }
    
    balance -= taxed(PHONE_PRICE, TAX_RATE);
    ++phoneQt;
    if (balance >= THRESHOLD) {
        balance -= taxed(ACCESSORIES_PRICE, TAX_RATE);
        ++accessoriesQT;
    }
}

console.log("You've bought " + (phoneQt + accessoriesQT) + " item");
console.log("And your balance is $" + balance.toFixed(2));
```

If the balance is 100, the result is:

```
You've bought 4 item
And your balance is $9.96
```

But, I've got an unexpected result when I change the while statement like this:

```
while (balance > MIN_PURCHASE) {
    balance -= taxed(PHONE_PRICE, TAX_RATE);
    phoneQt++;
    if (balance >= THRESHOLD) {
        balance -= taxed(ACCESSORIES_PRICE, TAX_RATE);
        accessoriesQT++;
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

The result I've got is:

```
You've bought 1 item
And your balance is $77.49
```

I think there's a problem in the while statement evaluation but I don't know how.

Comment: Actually, both your examples work fine, at least on Firefox, and both give 

*You've bought 5 item And your balance is $5.68*

In which browser/environment did you test them?

Comment: @rpadovani Google chrome

Comment: No, the 2nd code is wrong, it doesn't let you buy the last item, when it would cost exactly the amount you have in the balance. However all the results you posted make no sense starting from the code and values in your question

Answer (score 0):

Try >= instead of >

```
while (balance >= MIN_PURCHASE) {
    balance -= taxed(PHONE_PRICE, TAX_RATE);
    ++phoneQt;
    if (balance >= THRESHOLD) {
        balance -= taxed(ACCESSORIES_PRICE, TAX_RATE);
        ++accessoriesQT;
    }
}
```

Comment: when I run your code in my browser with starting balance of 100 I got: You've bought 5 item. And your balance is $5.68. And I got the exact same results with my code

Comment: I use snippet in Google Chrome

Comment: yes, but even your snippet gives me the same: 5 items, $5.68 left.

Comment: I try it on firefox and the results are as same as yours, It's really like that on my chrome.

Comment: I tried it on Chrome, Firefox, and on both I got 5 items, $5.68 left

Comment: after restarting my chrome, everything is fine thanks.

Comment: You mean this code or your 2nd version with the ">" and else {break} in the code>

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, you continue to buy phones even in the balance is lower than the threshold. In the second code smaple, you completely stop once you decide not to buy an accessory. Try removing the else clause.
Anyway, in both examples the result is the same - you buy 5 items. But still you should remove the else part.

Comment: the first case is what I am intending to do.